# How can I use method decorators before the constructor is called?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have some code that's allows you to define what happens on `christmas` without knowing anything about the underlying implementation or how the method is called e.g.,

```
# main.py
import lib.person
person = lib.person.Person()

@person.onchristmas()
def christmas():
    print "It's Christmas"
```

The implementation of the class is something like this:

```
# lib.person.py
class Person():

  def onchristmas(self):
    def decorator(f):
      self.christmas_handler = f
      return f
    return decorator

  def is_christmas(self):
    # called from somewhere else:
    self.christmas_handler()
```

The problem is that I can't import `main.py` without constructing a person. Similarly I can't move the constructor to be:

```
person = None

def init():

    person = lib.person.Person()
    return person
```

because then person would be NoneType and the decorators won't work. What the correct way to factor this code so that:

1. I can still use the decorator to let people implement their own `christmas` action without editing `lib.person.py`
2. I can construct person explicitly with `init()` instead of it happening on import.

EDIT FURTHER DETAIL FROM COMMENTS:

In actual fact there are many different things that can happen not just christmas, and there isn't just one handler per action there might be a number and all must execute:

So:

```
  def onchristmas(self):
    def decorator(f):
      self.christmas_handler.append(f)
      return f
    return decorator

  def is_christmas(self):
      # called from somewhere else:
      for h in self.christmas_handler:
          h()
```

Usage: I would like others to be able to specify the behavior of one or more actions without having to know how/when they will be called and ideally further down the line to be able to de-register handlers.

Also I should mention that there will only ever be on instance of Person, I'm not too familiar with static methods and singletons in Python though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your code defines separate "Christmas behavior" for each instance of `Person`.  You can't do that without creating an instance of `Person`.  Can you give an example of how you want the code to be used?  When a user defines a christmas action, what do you want it to apply to: all `Person`s, or just one?

Comment: Why not set `christmas_handler` explicitly without the decorator?

Comment: You appear to be exploiting the decorator syntax just to use a side-effect. This is the root of your confusion, since you'll need another decorator for each person you instantiate which doesn't really make sense. @C.B. has the right suggestion.

Comment: @BrenBarn What if there was only ever going to be one instance of Person. Would a singleton resolve that. Or maybe some kind of static method decorator if that is possible?

Comment: @nickponline: If there's only ever going to be one instance, why does it matter if it's created on import?  It has to be created sometime, and if you're never going to create another one, you might as well create that one right away.

Comment: @C.B. I'll add an edit of an example use case.

Comment: @BrenBarn yeah that's a good point. I just don't like the idea of that happening on import. Although I'm already doing some bad things :)

Comment: Given your use cases, I don't see why there's anything wrong with creating an instance on import.  It seems like you want the instance to be the API --- that is, you don't want users to interact with the `Person` class, only with one particular instance of it.  So just create that instance in your module.  It will be created on import and users can use it in the way you want.  No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the mixing of your decorator and your state. Why not break your decorator out of the class and allow your users to supply their own function. Such that the only state the decorator relies on is that which is supplied to it. Something similiar to this:

```
def christmas_config(user_defined_func):
   def inner_config(func):
       def f(*args, **kwargs):
          print 'Hey Yo'
          return user_defined_func(func, *args, **kwargs)
       return f
   return inner_config

def test(func, *args, **kwargs):
   print 'This is hairy'
   return func(*args, **kwargs)

@christmas_config(test)
def my_func():
   print 'test'

my_func()
```